# Oracle SQL - return multiple columns from subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, join, subquery

Let's take a simple query in Oracle:

```
SELECT
    CASE.ID,
    CASE.TYPE,
    CASE.DATE_RAISED
FROM
    CASE
WHERE
    CASE.DATE_RAISED > '2019-01-01'
```

Now let's say another table, EVENT, contains multiple events which may be associated with each case (linked via EVENT.CASE_ID). OR not exist at all. I want to report on the earliest-dated future event per case - or if nothing exists, return NULL. I can do this with a subquery in the SELECT clause, as follows:

```
SELECT
    CASE.ID,
    CASE.TYPE,
    CASE.DATE_RAISED,
    (
    SELECT
        MIN(EVENT.DATE)
    FROM
        EVENT
    WHERE
        EVENT.CASE_ID = CASE.ID
        AND EVENT.DATE >= CURRENT_DATE
    ) AS MIN_EVENT_DATE
FROM
    CASE
WHERE
    CASE.DATE_RAISED > '2019-01-01'
```

This will return a table like this:

```
Case ID Case Type   Date Raised Min Event Date
76      A           03/01/2019  10/05/2019
43      B           02/02/2019  [NULL]
89      A           29/01/2019  08/07/2019
90      A           04/03/2019  [NULL]
102     C           15/04/2019  20/05/2019
```

Note that if there do not exist any Events which match the criteria, the line is still returned but without a value. This is because the subquery is in the SELECT clause. This works just fine.

My problem, however, is if I want to return more than one column from the EVENT table - while still at the same time preserving the possibility that there are no matching rows from the EVENT table. The above code only returns EVENT.DATE as the single subquery result, to ONE column of the main query. But what if I also want to return EVENT.ID, or EVENT.TYPE? While still allowing for them to be NULL (if no matching records from CASE are found)?

I suppose I could use multiple subqueries in the SELECT clause: each returning just ONE column. But this seems horribly inefficient, given that each subquery would be based on the same criteria (the minimum-dated EVENT whose CASE ID matches that of the main query; or NULL if no such events found).

I suspect some nifty joins would be the answer - although I'm struggling to understand which ones exactly.

Please note that the above examples are vastly simplified versions of my actual code, which already contains multiple joins in the "old style" Oracle format, eg:

```
WHERE
    CASE.ID(+) = EVENT.CASE_ID
```

There are reasons why this is so - therefore a request to anyone answering this, please would you demonstrate any solutions in this style of coding, as my SQL isn't far enough advanced to be able to re-factor the "newer" style joins into existing code.

Comment: I would highly, highly recommend you stop writing queries in the "old style" join syntax. Refactoring existing queries into the new style is generally not difficult (unless there are some complex and weird joins in the existing sql.

Comment: To refactor, you need to identify the join conditions for the tables involved. If you edit your question to add an example of your query, we can refactor it for you. The "new" (it's been around for several years now) syntax is easier to understand, since your join conditions are no longer mixed in with the predicates.

Comment: @Boneist - I use the old style because this is where I first learned it, as it is generated in that form by the  *Business Objects* application. I started tweaking this generated code and introducing my own complexities - all while retaining the same style I learned. Most of the code I'm working with joins multiple tables in multiple ways, and I can't get my head around how to do this in the "new" style. This minimal example in the question may be easy to convert - but I wouldn't know where to start, with 10+ tables linked in different ways.

Comment: I too first learnt the old way, and used it for ~10 years. The “new way” is simply better. You can do more with it than the old way, and it’s really not that hard. If you’re stuck with generated sql from some app, though, that’s tougher.

Comment: @Boneist - If I were to provide a sample of the actual code I'm using (changing some names due to protection issues), would you be kind enough to show me a re-factor? This would be beyond the scope of this question though, so not sure where to ask it (Code Review?)

Comment: Create it as a new question and tag it with Oracle. However, I suggest you give it a go yourself first - it’s usually easy to go through the predicates and say “this one links table1 to table2 (and it’s an inner join), and these two link table2 to table3 (and it’s an outer join) etc. Once you have that, it’s literally `from table1 inner join table2 on <conditions> <left/right> outer join table3 on <conditions>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you mean? I just rewrote Gordon's answer with old Oracle join syntax and your code style.

```
SELECT
    CASE.ID,
    CASE.TYPE,
    CASE.DATE_RAISED,
    MIN_E.DATE AS MIN_EVENT_DATE
FROM
    CASE,
    (SELECT EVENT.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EVENT.CASE_ID ORDER BY EVENT.DATE DESC) AS SEQNUM
        FROM
            EVENT
        WHERE 
            EVENT.DATE >= CURRENT_DATE
    ) MIN_E
WHERE
    CASE.DATE_RAISED > DATE '2019-01-01'
    AND MIN_E.CASE_ID (+) = CASE.ID
    AND MIN_E.SEQNUM (+) = 1;
```

Comment: The use of the archaic outer join syntax that even Oracle doesn't want anyone to use any more causes a physical reaction in my stomach.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a `join` and window functions.  For instance:

```
select c.*, e.*
from c left join
     (select e.*,
             row_number() over (partition by e.case_id order by e.date desc) as seqnum
      from events e
     ) e
     on e.case_id = c.id and e.seqnum = 1;
where c.date_raised > date '2019-01-01';  -- assuming the value is a date
```

Comment: Can you please re-factor this into the style I requested in the question? I have no clue how to incorporate this style into my current code.

Comment: @ChrisMelville . . . I have no idea what your comment means.  This code should run as is (although you should probably list the columns that you want explicitly rather than using `*`).

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I see where you're going with this - and it basically worked, but for my lack of familiarity with how to employ this coding style. @kfinity used your logic and factored it into the form I understand. Still, have an up-vote :)

Answer (score 0):

Create object type with columns you want and return it from subquery. Your query will be like

```
SELECT
    CASE.ID,
    CASE.TYPE,
    CASE.DATE_RAISED,
    (
    SELECT
        t_your_new_type ( MIN(EVENT.DATE) , min ( EVENT.your_another_column ) )
    FROM
        EVENT
    WHERE
        EVENT.CASE_ID = CASE.ID
        AND EVENT.DATE >= CURRENT_DATE
    ) AS MIN_EVENT_DATE
FROM
    CASE
WHERE
    CASE.DATE_RAISED > '2019-01-01'
```